# Volley returns response object with value null and key is fine

Tags: java, android, android-volley, response

I am making a call to server sending data as an object to server . Following is the call to server. I checked request object on https://jsonlint.com and it appears to be valid. The call returns code 200 and everything is fine. But the response's value is null like `{"orderid":null}`. When I hit the api with postman ,the response is `{"orderid":"example123"}`
The code to call is :

```
public void orderfinal() {
    mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Cart.this);
    mStringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, carturl, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d("Response", "onResponse: " + response.toString());
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.i("This is the error", "Error :" + error.toString());
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        public String getBodyContentType() {
            return "application/json";
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String,String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError{
            Map<String, String> params= new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("Content-Type","application/json");
            return params;
        }

        @Override
        public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().serializeNulls().setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.UPPER_CAMEL_CASE).create();
            String json_string = gson.toJson(order_object);
            return json_string.getBytes();
        }
    };
    mRequestQueue.add(mStringRequest);

}
```

This is what my logcat prints:

```
D/Response: onResponse: {"orderid":null}
```

EDIT:
I just asked to make changes to API and if the server returns just a string like `abc`, the log prints it correctly. If the response is changed to `123` instead of `abc` , the log prints `0` no matter what the response string is. And please note that the object had the value of `orderid` as a number. For example `{"orderid":"00012"}` and the log showed `{"orderid":null}`.

Comment: I am sending the object as the body of the request so I have to override `getBody()` . And I am just logging the value. Not doing anything at all. Just logging it by converting it into string. Does it still matter?

Comment: Try printing `json_string` it could be different than in postman.

Comment: No its not. I logged the `json_string`. Copied it from log and pasted it on postman as body. So its totally same.

Comment: And to my surprise, If the response is not an object and just `abc` , the log prints it correctly. And if the response is a number like `123` instead of `abc`, the log prints `0`.

Comment: Debug your server side because we don't know if the App is sending correct information.

Comment: Only the field orderid is null or all the fields?

Comment: there is only one field in response that is orderid and its null

Comment: When you're doing the same request on postman, doesn't it put the encoding? Maybe you could try to add return "application/json; charset=utf-8"; on getBodyContentType and on getBody you could change getBytes for .getBytes("utf-8")